# Why does a browser attach cookies to requests originating from another origin?

Tags: http, cookies, browser, same-origin-policy

From RFC6265 section 8.2:

> A server that uses cookies to authenticate users can suffer security
>      vulnerabilities because some user agents let remote parties issue
>      HTTP requests from the user agent (e.g., via HTTP redirects or HTML
>      forms).  When issuing those requests, user agents attach cookies even
>      if the remote party does not know the contents of the cookies,
>      potentially letting the remote party exercise authority at an unwary
>      server.

In trying to understand SOP it's clear that this is the case, but I can't find anything on why this is the case. What benefits are conferred by blindly attaching all cookies for every request to origin A, even if the request originates from a different and possibly malicious origin B?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might seem strange at first, and maybe it is not the best idea, but here it shouldn't be an issue in most cases:

- the responses of the request are blocked by SOP, so no information is leaked anyways
- POST request (and any state-altering requests) should be protected by a CSRF protection method anyways

Plus, if the browsers didn't behave that way, servers with permissive CORS rules would be  blocked from functioning properly.